# Calculate the following integral: $\int \sqrt[3]{1+x\ln{x}} \cdot (1+\ln{x}) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, radicals

I have to calculate the following integral

$$    \int \sqrt[3]{1+x\ln{x}} * (1+\ln{x}) dx$$

I have thought about using the following notation:

$$ t = {1+x\ln(x)} \Rightarrow x\ln{x} = t-1 $$

But here I get stuck as I'm not completely sure how to get $x$ alone, my only solution would be

$$ x^x = e^{t-1} $$ Not sure how that would actually help me tho.

How do I get that x alone and also , am I on the right track with this notation?

Comment: What's $dt$ if $t=1+x\log x$?

Comment: Well, dt = lnx + 1 ? Oh god, I'm so stupid lol.

Comment: You can use `$\Rightarrow$` $\Rightarrow$ or `$\implies$` $\implies$. I think that either of them looks a bit better than $=>$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$t = {1+x\ln(x)} \iff  dt=(\ln x+1) dx$$

$$\int (1+\ln{x}) \sqrt[3]{1+x\ln{x}} dx=\int  \sqrt[3]{t} dt=\frac{3t^{4/3}}{4}+C=\frac{3}{4}(1+\ln x)^{4/3}+C$$

And here's the *amazing* result

> $$\int (1+\ln{x}) \sqrt[3]{1+x\ln{x}} dx=\frac{3}{4} (1+\ln{x}) \sqrt[3]{1+x\ln{x}}+C$$

Comment: Yeah, I was kinda blind and tried to get x alone before calculating dt. Thnx a lot :)

Comment: You have to wait 10 minutes before accepting.

Answer (score 2):

The substitution you're doing is good! Just observe that, from $t=1+x\log x$, we get
$$
dt=(1+\log x)\,dx
$$
and you're almost done.